# The email cannot send to the email distribution list with period dot when using database mail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created an email distribution list called my.test@outlook.com. I'm creating a stored procedure to create an email alert report for the company use. But the problem now is the email distribution list cannot receive the email when I execute the sp_send_dbmail.

I already checked the sent_status in sysmail_allitems, it show sent. And I checked for the database mail log, it show the databasemail process is started and the databasemail process is shutting down. I tried to send the test E-mail in database mail also cannot. And I tried to send the email by using Microsoft Outlook, the member of the email distribution list can receive the email. Only when using the database mail, they cannot receive the email. I check in junk or spam email, there is nothing inside there. The server name is gmail.com. The port number is 25. And the SMTP authentication is anonymous authentication. Can I know will the dots inside the email address of the email distribution list cause the member of the email distribution list cannot receive the email?

Below is just the example of query to exec the sp_send_dbmail, not the full code of the stored procedure.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='testing',
@recipients = 'my.test@outlook.com',
@subject = 'This email is for testing purpose',
@body = 'Hi all, this email is for testing purpose';
```

Can someone help me to about this problem? Your kind help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: GMail doesn't allow unencrypted SMTP over port 25, you need to use port 587 and SSL. And you need an App Password from GMail

Comment: An Outlook distribution list is not an email address.  It is a group that is defined solely within Outlook and is not accessible to external email systems.  The group needs to be changed and an actual email address assigned - then you can email to that SMTP address.

Comment: May I know if the server name is using the company own server name, is the port number still need to use the port 587? Because if I using the default company server name, port number and SMTP authentication to send the email to others email (non email distribution list), the email can sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Steven and welcome to SOF ! These are the steps you can follow to solve your issue :

- Try to verify your database mail configuration by checking if the Database Mail feature is enabled on the SQL Server instance.
- Make sure that the mail profile used in the @profile_name parameter of sp_send_dbmail is correctly set up and enabled.
- If you have access to the SMTP server settings try to check that the information provided are correct (server name, port number, authentication method).
- Verify that the email address 'my.test@outlook.com' is correct and exists and it is not being blocked or filtered by any spam filters or firewall settings.
- You can check the email delivery logs or reports provided by the email service provider to see if any errors or rejections are logged.
- Also try to test with a different email address (not the distribution list) by  using sp_send_dbmail.

Comment: Hi Amira, the Database Mail feature is enabled on the SQL Server instance. The mail profile used in the @profile_name parameter of sp_send_dbmail is set up correctly and enabled. I already provided the smtp server setting in my post. I already verify that email, it can receive the email when using Microsoft Outlook. I already tried to test with a different email address (not the distribution list) by using sp_send_dbmail, the sp_send_dbmail can send the email successfully.